# Mailto link with display name in non-Latin characters doesn't work correctly in Chrome browser

Tags: html, email, google-chrome, encoding, mailto

I have the following problem in Chrome browser: 
When I have a mailto link with display name in non-Latin characters and email address the right button->copy email address->paste anywhere  doesn’t work correctly. The display name is broken /with escape characters/.

For example:

`<a href="mailto:нова категория <7580397996@gmail.com>?Subject=[Enter your subject title here]&body=[Enter your content email here]">нова категория</a>`

If you try this in Chrome Copy Email Address doesn’t work correctly.
Does anyone know how can I fix this problem or this problem is bug in Chrome?

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, mailto links are not designed to take a name for the recipient, but rather a mailto url. You might want to have a look at the mailto URL theme: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt

Comment: @peterp that RFC simply references RFC822 which states that the full mailbox spec is allowed. i.e. what he's trying to do should be perfectly allowable. The problem is with chrome copying it to the clipboard.

Comment: @adhocgeek Thanks for pointing this out, I have overlooked that part. janiat, Have you tried to url encode the string?

Comment: Hi @peterp, 
The original code is in Java and the string is URL encoded.

This is the code: 
`ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(categoryName)`

categoryName – display name

Comment: @janiat HTML encoding is not URL encoding. HTML encoding converts `&` to `&amp`, URL encoding converts it to `%26`. The target of a mail link is actually called "mailto **URL**", so I think it should rather be URL-encoded. Try `URLEncoder.encode(String)`